# .net obfuscation for reflected methods

Tags: .net, reflection, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate my application.  However, I use a lot of reflection in it, especially `Type.GetMethod` in order to create generic methods with a dynamic type.

Ex:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MethodInfo info = this.GetType().GetMethod("ShowInMessageBox", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        MethodInfo generic = info.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

        String result = (String)generic.Invoke(this, new Object[] { 1234 });

        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }

    [Obfuscation(Exclude =true)]
    private String ShowInMessageBox<T>(T item)
    {
        return item.ToString();
    }
```

However, both **ConfuserEx** and **Dotfuscator** will not change the string in `GetMethod("ShowInMessageBox")` and so my application will simply not work once obfuscated.

Other than using   `[Obfuscation(Exclude =true)]`, is there an other way to successfully obfuscate reflected methods?

Comment: Give them obfuscated names in code?

Comment: Can you switch your strings to use the `nameof(` operator instead?

Comment: nameof would have been a good idea, I agree.  However, it doesn't like either ConfuserEx nor Dotfuscator handles them properly.

Comment: `nameof` is resolved at compile time, the result is the same as writing the method's name.

Comment: Depending on your actual use case you could implement the resolution of methods/types using custom attributes instead of strings.

Comment: You could use Linq expression bodies to get the name of the method at runtime rather than at compile time.